# Avoiding hardcoded string in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I often put a hard coding sample string in `TextView` when I designing layout. I do that to overview how it will be see all together. It is certainly i put actual data in `TextView` in apps code.

This is cause of warning "*Hardcoded string ... should use @string resource*". I know it may be suppressed with something like that `xxx:ignore="HardcodedText"`, but this enlarge the XML code and consume CPU time when inflate not needed attribute `android:text="FOO"`.

Is there any xml attribute to fill a TextView for layout design purpose only without negative influence to performance on runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you can do is have a placeholder string in `strings.xml` then each time you create a textview just put that as the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tools:text="this text will only appear in the layout editor"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I search.